# Pagination with Asp.Net from an XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, pagination

i need to do a Pagination with just Asp.Net (no ajax call or jquery at all). And i have to get the data from an XML.

The XML it's something like this

```
<node>
  <id></id> // This is a Guid type of ID.
  <mail></mail>
  <name></name>
</node>
```

Ideas?

Comment: So, what's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: sorry, i already've done it. thanks any way.